# Generating a byte with an array of bit positions?

Tags: python, binary

Let's say I have a list of numbers:

`[1, 2, 5]`

I need to generate a byte that represents the 5, 2 and 1 "position on". Which will result in the byte of value 19.

`00010011`

Is there an easy way to do this that doesn't involve me playing with an array of ones and zeros and them trying to convert it to a byte?

Comment: The least significant bit is normally designated as bit 0, not bit 1.  This corresponds to the multiplier being 2\*\*0 i.e. 1, not 2\*\*1 i.e. 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `2**(n-1)` will set a bit in the position you want:

```
print(bin(2**(1-1))) # 00001
print(bin(2**(2-1))) # 00010
print(bin(2**(5-1))) # 10000
```

This is equivalent to bit shifting:

```
1<<(1-1) # 00001
1<<(2-1) # 00001
1<<(5-1) # 10000
```

You can sum `2**(n-1)` for each number in your list:

```
nums = [1, 2, 5]

print(sum(2**(x-1) for x in nums))
```

Which results in the same result in applying the 'and' operation on each of the binary numbers:

```
00001
00010 AND
10000 AND
-----
10011
```

Which is equal to 19.

You can convert this to binary using the bin function:

```
print(bin(sum(2**(x-1) for x in nums)))

Output:
0b10011
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `sum(1<<(i-1) for i in nums)` to make the bit-like nature of the computation more apparent.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yep, I just tried to use more common math as the question asked to not use arrays of ones and zeros, so I assumed little knowledge of binary. I have updated the question with some explanation of what is happening.

Comment: This solution, like the problem statement, uses unnatural bit numbering.  You could get rid of all those pointless `- 1` operations if it used the standard convention of numbering the low-order bit `0` rather than `1`.  Also, using shift operators is likely more efficient (and cleaner) than using exponentiation.

Comment: @TomMcLean yes, extremely low knowledge of binary (the best I can do is write them all down and count from right to left). You help me immensely. Your approach using exponential to calculate the "position of the bit", and then sum all of them together is so simple and elegant. I love it.

Comment: @JohnColeman Going to be honest, I did not even remember what was the bitwise operator. But it looks very nice.

Comment: @TomKarzes The question used the low-order bit as 1 and the question implied little knowledge of binary operations, hence the use of exponentiation. If the function is to be used between non-programmers, then performance is not an issue, readability is. You are welcome to add an answer.

Comment: @TomKarzes In addition, the quesiton doesnt ask about performance. On my machine, for small numbers, the power operaiton is faster than bit shifting.

Comment: @TomMcLean For larger values I expect shifting would be faster.  Also, I would expect bitwise-OR to be marginally faster than addition when combining the results for large numbers, although since there are no carries it probably makes virtually no difference.